# Who wins if we have multiple temporary Asynchronous pluggable protocol for same schema?

Tags: internet-explorer, pluggableprotocol

Suppose we have more than one temp Async pluggable protocols for schema lets say ftp: then which one will be called by urlmon?

Comment: My guess would be whichever one is in the registry first.

Comment: But this is temp protocol , it gets registered by calling RegsiterNamespace API.
So I guess registry is not involved here.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs when multiple handlers are registered for a namespace then last past the post wins, this also implies that temporary handlers trump those declared in the registry.

Excerpt from [IInternetSession::RegisterNameSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767759.aspx) on MSDN:

> Because pluggable protocol handlers are not chained, only the last handler to be registered will be active; therefore, it is better to create a new namespace, rather than reuse an existing one.